# Change view frame in landscape using autolayout in storyboard

Tags: ios, ipad, orientation, autolayout, landscape

I am very new to `AutoLayout`. I have one problem. I need to change the frame of any `UIView` when moving form portrait to landscape mode.

For example: If I have one `UILabel` with frame (100,100,100,30) in portrait mode. And I want to change its frame to (400,400,100,30) if rotate iPad to landscape mode. I want to do this using storyboard and auto layout.

I want to avoid coding for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I try this one :

First check **Use AutoLayout**

[image]

Move your mouse point to `UILabel` and drag right side with **Ctrl** Key and select **Trailing space to container**

[image]

Move your mouse point to `UILabel` and drag left side with **Ctrl** Key and select **Leading space to container**

[image]

This is your output :

[image]
  [image]

Check it. :)

Answer (score 0):

This will help your in autolayout
please see the given below images

[image: Apply the process with screen shot 1]

[image: Apply the process with screen shot 2]

[image: Apply the process with screen shot 3]

Comment: you need to explain your answer.